# How to ignore "order" class on mobile in Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Is there a way to ignore the order class on larger screens?

I have two inputs with a label that goes like this;

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-12 col-md-5 order-first order-md-5"><label class="form-label">Label for 1st input <small>(Explanation for first input)</small></label></div>
  <div class="col-12 col-md-5 offset-md-2 order-last order-md-10"><label class="form-label">Label for 2n input<small>( Explanation for second input )</small></label></div>
  <div class="col-12 col-md-5 order-first order-md-5">
    <div class="form-group mt-2">
      <input autocomplete="off" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-12 col-md-2 align-self-center">
    <p class="form-group text-center mt-3">and/or</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-12 col-md-5 order-last order-md-10">
    <div class="form-group mt-2">
      <input autocomplete="off" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

They work just as I want them to on mobile, however, I need them to look like they were as before I have added the order classes which look like

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-12 col-md-5"><label class="form-label">Label for 1st input <small>(Explanation for first input)</small></label></div>
  <div class="col-12 col-md-5 offset-md-2"><label class="form-label">Label for 2n input<small>( Explanation for second input )</small></label></div>
  <div class="col-12 col-md-5">
    <div class="form-group mt-2">
      <input autocomplete="off" type="text" class="form-control"  placeholder="">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-12 col-md-2 align-self-center">
    <p class="form-group text-center mt-3">and/or</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-12 col-md-5">
    <div class="form-group mt-2">
      <input autocomplete="off" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Ordering is correct on mobile and just as I want, but it breaks the desktop order. Ordering without the order classes is perfect on the desktop for me, but it breaks the mobile order. Is there a way to activate the order classes on mobile only?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add class like .order-1 insted of order-first and all related classes hope that work for you.